# Want to integrated angular 4 with spring boot app

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have an existing Spring Boot (version -1.5.9 ) production web app with the integration of angularjs (Version 1.6). 
Now I want to replace angluarjs(1.6) with Angular 4. This is sample code the way spring boot app and angluarjs(1.6) app is integrated 
https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-springboot-angularjs-bootstrap-springdata-j.
 Any idea how can I do with Angular 4.

Answer (score 0):

The example that you shared is on Angular 2+ (2, 4, 5, 6, ...), you could follow what the tutorial says, the main part about integration is in 'HttpBaseService' of your tutorial, you only need connect to you Spring App via HttpClient, you can see https://angular.io/guide/http (official Angular documentation) to understand how this works, and see the examples.